# Load page with ajax and scroll to loaded page anchor

Tags: javascript, ajax

I load a page with ajax and I want main page to auto scroll to the beginning of loaded page.
Here is the code I use:

html

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" id="photos"> <i class="fa fa-plus fa-5x"></i><br>Add Photo</button>
```

and at the bottom of the page I have this js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#photos").click(function(){
    $(".content-loader").fadeOut('slow', function()
    {
        $(".content-loader").fadeIn('slow');
        $(".content-loader").load('somepage.php?pid=3');
    });
});
```

The above works fine and page 'somepage.php?pid=3' is loaded in 
`<div class="content-loader">`.
How can I make the page to autoscroll to `<div class="content-loader">` when page 'somepage.php?pid=3' is loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: Just wrap the above in the success call back of `load()`

Comment: also bear in mind [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following should work for the `.load()` function. It should scroll on load complete

```
$(".content-loader").load('somepage.php?pid=3', function () {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".content-loader").offset().top});
});
```